# How do I add a 2D view inside a 3D SCNNode in Scene Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, scenekit, scnnode

I'm trying to add a type of "notification" above a 3D view that follows it and if the camera rotates or the SCNNode rotates that view always stay looking front, it's to "expensive" to do calculations and make a flat 3D and rotate it every time some of the parents rotates, or the camera, and I don't want to add an UIView over everything that is following the 3D xyz because I want it to interact with the 3D worls depth-sorting.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

[image: Example]

It's a view that doesn't rotate with it's parents, how do I achieve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so basically you rotate the banner in the opposite direction of its parent (always facing camera), done. Why should that be too expensive?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It's a game an it involves tons of nodes, there will be lots of fors going on just to rotate the banners plus you're free of rotating the camera, so there will be lots of calculations.

Comment: you can use shader modifiers to do that, and if you work in view space (the coordinate system of the camera) everything becomes simple. You can look for "billboard shader" on the web.

Comment: it's a game, there *will* be lots of calculations. Don't not do something because you are afraid it might be slow. Make it work and when you find a performance problem, then you analyse and optimize.

Comment: plus, I betbthat if you have tons of nodes, chances are that the rotation calculations will hardly contribute at all, most games are entirely gpu limited ie it takes a lot more time to draw a 3d model than some measly offset calculations.

Comment: I just found this: `nodeA.constraints = @[[SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstraintWithTarget:nodeB]];`it makes something always look at some other thing, this is perfectly what I need, I'll test it out and post it as an answer if I succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way of doing it, it's really simple as this:

```
SCNLookAtConstraint *constraint = [SCNLookAtConstraint lookAtConstraintWithTarget:cameraNode];
constraint.gimbalLockEnabled = YES;
nodeA.constraints = @[constraint];
```

This will make the **nodeA** always look at the camera and I set the `gimbalLockEnabled = YES` so it doesn't rotate weirdly.

Hope it helps someone out there, it saved my game :-)

Comment: Nice creative use of `SCNLookAtConstraint`!

Comment: Looks like it facing toward, not forward :(